# Updating sql field using textarea

Tags: html, sql, textarea

I got a problem with setting up textarea.
I need multiline textbox so Im using textarea.
in old system It was input like:

`< input type="hidden" name="ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION" value="<%=ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION%>">`

What that is doing. This is taking data from sql table and showing for user. Everything is working to moment where user want update data, after he type something and save it field in sql is cleared and old data is deleted. When I use input its working normally and that happends only when I use textarea:

`<textarea cols="80"; rows="4";name="ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION" > <%=ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION%>"</textarea>`

Thanks for help

Comment: Your textarea should be `<textarea cols="80" rows="4" name="ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION"><%=ADDITIONAL_PRICE_INFORMATION%></textarea>`

Comment: @Agony -- I don't think `textarea` uses the `value` attribute.

Comment: @sgeddes Good point. Edited. (Not sure if that would work though...)

Comment: Removing " ; " not helps and still when I want to put some data into the filed using this textbox cousing that the field is empty